# Proof from Natanson's book : Cardinality of the set of all real-valued functions defined on the segment $\left[0,1\right]$

Tags: analysis, set-theory

***Isidor Pavlovich Natanson - Theory of Functions of a Real Variable. Vol I 1983, Theorem 1, page 28***

> Theorem 1. The set F of all real-valued functions defined on the segment $\left[0,1\right]$ has cardinality greater than c.

Proof:

> We first show that
>   $$F\text{ is not }\sim U$$
>   where $U=\left[0,1\right]$. Let us assume, on the contrary, that $F\sim U$ and let $\varphi$ be a one-to-one correspondence between $F$ and $U$. We denote by $f_{t}\left(x\right)$ the function in $F$ which corresponds to the number $t\in\left[0,1\right]$ under the correspondence $\varphi$. We set
>   $$F\left(t,x\right)=f_{t}\left(x\right)$$
>   This is a completely defined function of the two variables $x$ and $t$, defined in the region $0\leq t\leq1$, $0\leq x\leq1$. We now set
>   $$\psi\left(x\right)=F\left(x,x\right)+1$$
>   This function is defined for $0\leq x\leq1$, *i.e.*, $\psi\left(x\right)\in F$. But then the function $\psi\left(x\right)$ corresponds to some number $a\in U$ under the correspondence $\varphi$, *i.e.*, $\psi\left(x\right)=f_{a}\left(x\right)$, or
>   $$\psi\left(x\right)=F\left(a,x\right)$$
>   In other words,
>   $$F\left(x,x\right)+1=F\left(a,x\right)$$
>   for all $x$ in $\left[0,1\right]$. But this is impossible, as we see on setting $x=a$. It follows that $F$ is not $\sim U$.

At first, I felt I understand the logic of the proof. But, after when I saw an example

> But if we consider the set of functions
>   $$F^{*}=\left\{\sin x+t\right\}\quad\quad\left(0\leq t\leq1\right)$$
>   which is a subset of $F$, then we see at once that $F^{*}\sim U$, and the theorem is proved.

It's obviously that each function of $F^{*}$ corresponds to a number $t$ of $\left[0,1\right]$.
But, if I adapt the logic of the proof to this example:
Let $G=\left\{\sin x+t\right\}\cup\left\{\sin x + x + 1\right\}$. ($G$ has the same cardinality as $F^{*}$)
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
G\left(t,x\right) & = & f_{t}\left(x\right)\\
& = & \sin x + t\\
\psi\left(x\right)& = & G\left(x,x\right)+1\\
& = & \sin x + x + 1
\end{eqnarray*}$$
And it let to $G\left(x,x\right)+1=G\left(a,x\right)$, as the proof above.
I'm now very confused:

1. Is $F\left(x,x\right)$ established by correspondence $\varphi$, by replacing $t$ with $x$?
   Is it right that $G\left(x,x\right)=\sin x + x$?
2. What is wrong with my adaption on this example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same old Cantor's diagonal argument with which the distinction between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ was made; if you understood that, then you should understand this as well.

As for your construction: the diagonal function $\psi$ produced from $F^*$ is $\sin x+x+1$, which is **not** of the form $\sin x+t$, hence it is not in $F^*$ and not in the one-to-one correspondence with some number from $(0,1)$, which was crucial for the next step. OK, you try to mend that by incorporating this function into your set. But then you should start from scratch with $G$: take a one-to-one correspondence between $G$ and $[0,1]$, and so on. The proposed $t\leftrightarrow G_t(x)=\sin x+t$ would not do: it includes all numbers from $[0,1]$, but *not* all functions from $G$.

So it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know Cantor's diagonal argument. Actually, I thought about the first case you mentioned ($\sin x + x + 1 \notin F^{*}$), so I include $\sin x + x + 1$ in $F^{*}$ But, I don't understand your last paragraph. I meant, if add a finite or countable number of elements to an infinite set, then the cardinality of this set is not change, as a theorem proposed in this book. That is $G\sim F^{*}$.

Comment: Of course the cardinality will not change. It's not cardinality that breaks the argument. There is still one-to-one correspondence between $G$ and $[0,1]$, only it is **not** $t\leftrightarrow G_t(x)=\sin x+t$ (which you relied upon).

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, that the correspondence, such as $\varphi:t\leftrightarrow F^{*}_{t}$, and my fault is, to adapt this $\varphi$ with $G$ will let the "paradox".

Comment: OK! I think I understand now!